# Android: Webview-Javascript-Interaction fails; Object has no methods when compiling in RELEASE-Mode

Tags: javascript, android, webview

in my Android-App I use WebViews, in which javascript interacts with my Acitvity.
I use the commond known addJavascriptInterface method and the object's methods have the necessary annotation @JavascriptInterface as shown below:

```
getWebview().addJavascriptInterface(
             new Object() {

                 @JavascriptInterface
                 public void toast(String _v) {
                     Toast.makeText(delegate, " mein Javascripttoast: "+_v, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

             }
             , "toast"
     );
```

My manifest file contains the following target sdk definition:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

If I run my app in DEBUG mode using eclipse everything works fine. The problem occurs when building the app in RELEASE mode for publishing on the Google Play store. The generated javascript object used for interaction doesn't contain any methods now. But it only occurs in RELEASE mode.

I have examined the problem with dumping the objects, etc. but those are empty.

My test devices are an Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3 on it and a Galaxy S2 with Android 4.1.3 installed.

I tested all day and haven't any further ideas. Can somebody help?

Comment: are you using proguard/some sort of obfuscation?

Answer (score 0):

This is because when compiling in release mode, it runs it through [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) which strips out your JavaScript interface.

To solve this, you need to edit your proguard.pro file.